# Block only specified ads on a website, ignoring the patterns in the list

Tags: firefox, adblock

On http://www.marktplaats.nl using the AdBlock extension in Firefox breaks some functionality.
Therefore I disabled the extension on that website. Now everything works as it should but obviously ads are shown.

I have the idea that a rule in the [filter list I'm subscribed to](https://easylist-downloads.adblockplus.org/easylist.txt) breaks the website, but as the list is very long I can not check the rules one-by-one to determine the error.

The ad is contained in a div which I can easily block with the rule `##div#title`. 
However this does not work when the site is in the exception list, even when the exceptions are placed after/below the ad blocking rules:

[image]

Can I bypass all filter rules in the subscribed list and only use the rule I specify for this specific site?

Comment: Try Ghostery add-on you can choose what to enable and what to disable.

Comment: Could you maybe elaborate in an answer on how I would block a div with it?